# Run X11 programs and render on cloud machine without a physical screen

Tags: linux, x11, xorg, x-server, display-manager

I am trying to run a program that uses X11 to display (assume xeyes or something similar) on a machine in the cloud (ec2, Compute Engine, etc). I understand that I can get the windows to show up on my X11 server if I use the `-X` option when I ssh into the server. But I am trying to actually display the windows on that machine (I know that doesn't really make sense why I would need that but I have some video recording programs that need it). How would I go about doing this? I am trying to make a somewhat scalable solution.

I have a machine at my house that I am testing on. I have ubuntu desktop 20.04 on it. If I log into the normal way (keyboard, mouse, display) then I can `ps aux | grep X` and see the X server running. And if I ssh into the machine I can see the same thing and then change my `DISPLAY` environment variable and launch graphical programs on that machine. But if I do not log into the machine via Ubuntu Desktop then there is not an X server running and I can not launch programs. I understand that this is probably the way things were intended to be. I want to "trick" the machine into thinking that there is a display attached.

I've tried launching x from ssh by running `startx` and I get `Only console users are allowed to run the X server` I don't know If I should be trying to start Ubuntu Desktop from ssh or if I should be doing something entirely different to get X11 programs to run.

I have some general X11 questions that would also help with my task

- Who does the actually rendering on X? If I am an XClient do I render all of my graphic and send raw pixels to the X-Server to display them? Or does the XClient send some representation of the window it wants rendered and the XServer renders it. I.E. if I had a super fast GPU and the XServer and XClient were running on seperate machines which machine would I want the GPU to be on?
- Does X11 only recognize a display if it sees an actual input plugged into the computer (HDMI, VGA) or can you have pure software displays that it can render to?

I'm open to reading any resources that could help me with this problem. Any help to any parts of this is appreciated. Thanks!

Edit 1:
The actually use case is proprietary but the idea is that I am trying to render a chrome window and record the output of the window over time to a video file. I would like it to be very scalable so it be setup and launched easily.

Comment: Yes! The remote does not have a screen. I am connecting to it via ssh from my local machine and trying to launch x11 programs on it.

Comment: There are software only X11-servers. I can't remember so only a comment: look at xephyr, xnest (older), There is also at least one of the VNC servers (you can connect remotely to it via VNC or not).

Comment: I removed reference to `ssh` it title, as it suggests the wrong thing (X11 over ssh).